# How to auto capture an image using my mobile camera?

Tags: android, service, camera

I'm new to coding.
My requirement is, auto capture of photos using my mobile camera
Can anyone help to sort out my problem, thanks in advance.

I have been trying from past three days,
please solve my problem if anyone is interested

```
 public class ServiceActivity extends Activity {
String msg = "Android : ";
View view;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
}

public void startService(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraService.class));
}

// Method to stop the service
public void stopService(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CameraService.class));
}}
```

below is the service code from which camera of my mobile should be opened automatically then a snapshot should be taken without tapping the camera button then it should be stored in local storage

```
 public class CameraService extends Service {
static int x=0;
//Camera variables
//a surface holder
private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
//a variable to control the camera
private Camera mCamera;
//the camera parameters
private android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mCamera = Camera.open();
    SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());


    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        //set camera parameters
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Get a surface
    sHolder = sv.getHolder();
    //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
    sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}



Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
{

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try{
            x++;
            outStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Image"+x+".jpg");
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            mCamera.release();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "picture clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
};
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: So the camera is opened automatically, and a snapshot taken and saved to file. All automatically. Nice. Well done.

Comment: @blackapps do you know how to do it

Comment: You did not understand my comment. If you have any problems then put them in your post. And then ask. I see no problems. I see no questions.

Comment: You should exactly tell what not works. You told nothing precise. Is it only the saving to file that does not work? We dont know! You should tell what exactly happens and what not. Dont let us guess. PUT IT ALL IN YOUR POST.

Comment: @blackapps Camera is not taking a photo

Comment: @Stella Do you receive any errors? If so, can you please put them in your question so someone can analyse and possibly tell you what is wrong, thanks.